# Bootstrap 3, windows phone internet explorer Device-Width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about bootstrap 3, I am trying to create a site but the mobile resolution is bit too small.

On my Windows phone bootstrap homepage/navbar is in much more bigger compared to the online sample, why is that?

also I tried to compare the sites in online resolution emulator, but there they are the same size?

- [problem image](http://imgur.com/4JwpVzT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I go answer for my question, first of all documentation mentions windows phone explorer: [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support)

so i added to my index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
        appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
</script>
```

and also i added this to my style.css file

```
@-webkit-viewport{width:device-width}
@-moz-viewport{width:device-width}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
@-o-viewport{width:device-width}
@viewport{width:device-width}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an emulator if so the screen res may not be true. Always test on actual devices if possible.